# C# how to remove escaped quotes from string response

Tags: c#, restsharp

So this is the response I'm getting back from my restsharp call:

[image]

Maybe I'm not looking for the right stuff, but I can't find anywhere online how to easily deserialize a string response to remove the \".

It's not a JSON response, it's just a string. Anyone know how can I get my response to just be `"35479CCAB8"`?

EDIT:

To those saying escaped characters usually show in the debugger, I don't think that is always the case. Here is another line of code I viewed from the debugger:

[image]

Comment: Those escaped quotes are just shown in your debugger.  They aren't part of the actual string content.  Your actual string contains quotes but not the escape character.  And a simple string `"example"` is a valid JSON response.

Comment: Really? I feel like usually when i view a string in the debugger the escaped characters don't show

Comment: If you click that magnifying glass they'll disappear, as it will be using the string visualizer.

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt Yes, really.  ;)  If you click on the magnifying glass, you'll see it without the escapes though.

Comment: @Wyck can you check my edit?

Comment: The string in your edit doesn't contain any escaped characters! Just the value `Firefox` the debugger wraps the string with double quotes so you get `"Firefox"` and you know it's a string value.

Comment: @phuzi i know! my question is asking how i can remove the escaped characters from the original string i posted so it looks like the one I posted in my edit

Comment: Just trim the doubles quotes, they are only escaped in the debugger `string.Trim('"')`

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt Your original string contained double quotes.  It did not contain escaped double quotes.  Your debugger is escaping them when presenting it to you.  Your new string doesn't contain any double quotes.  It's just a string.

Comment: @Amy Yeah i see that now, thanks. Didn't realize that my restsharp response actually contained extra quotes which was confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
var token = shippingCalcualtion.token.Trim('"');
```

`Trim(...)` will remove all given trailing and leading characters from your string. In this case `'\"'`. Restsharp will deserialize what's given, so if it should deserialize `"test"` (the value provided through the network stack) it will be deserialized to `\"test\"`.

### Edit:

if you click the magnifying glass on your 2nd example you will get only `Firefox` without `"..."`. In this case the `"` is not part of the string itself, but in `shippingCalcualtion.token` the string contains one leading and trailing `"`.

Comment: The `"` does not need to be escaped when its enclosed in single quotes like that.  If you intended to replace the `\ ` character, then that character needs to be escaped, but that character wasn't part of the original string anyway.

Comment: This worked, thanks. The whole thing with the debugger escaping the quotes when the response itself actually just had quotes in it was throwing me for a loop. Makes sense now